# How long does the Firebase auth user session last in background service worker of chrome extension MV3?

Tags: firebase, google-chrome-extension, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase auth in a Chrome extension but via Background service worker instead of content script or popup.

I'm using [signInWithCustomToken](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/custom-auth#authenticate-with-firebase) method in Background service worker to login user for the first time using a custom token which I get from the server.

Background SW:

```js
const cred = await signInWithCustomToken(authClient, token);
```

Background SW in MV3 becomes inactive after ~30s but I can see that Firebase auth is still persisted if I query the auth state by sending a message to bgsw.

from content script:

```js
await chrome.runtime.sendMessage({action:"getUserAuthState"});
```

in BGSW:

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (
    request: RequestMessage,
    sender,
    sendResponse
  ) {
    const action = request.action;
    switch (action) {
      case "getUserAuthState": {
        sendResponse(authClient.currentUser); //get firebase user
        break;
      }
  
      default:
        break;
    }
  });
```

custom token expires in an hour so I can't use it repeatedly to authenticate user. So, for how long does the user session persist in background service worker? is it through the lifetime till user logs out just like in any web app where Firebase auth is implemented?